# How much data willa Linux pipe buffer? Can a linux pipe buffer size configurable?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, pipe, ipc

How much data can a Linux pipe buffer? Is this configurable?

And does it make a difference if both ends of the pipe are in the same process, but different threads?

Please note: this "same process, two threads" question is a theoretical side bar, the real question is about buffering.

Comment: `man 7 pipe` from a shell will answer many of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

As per "ulimit -a" (thanks to an out-of-band suggestion), is very small, about 512 bytes.